# I have a .json file containing a list of orders, how do I get python to get this data and load it into a list?

Tags: python, list, compilation

I have a document with a list of orders, how do I get python to compile a list of the order Id's in the file? I have got it to read the file, with 
file = open('Orders_example.json') 
print(file.read()) 
However I need the file to be saved to a list in python, how do I do this? I have checked the file you have question you have asked and it doesn't work, it comes up with*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jess/Documents/The one.py", line 3, in 
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())*

Comment: Take a look at the json module.

Comment: My code looks like this import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('Orders_example.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

pprint(data)*
And I get an error code looking like this *Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jess/Documents/Start Fresh.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.load(data_file)*